# remove double backslash from a list in python

Tags: python

i trying to add a path to list but removing the double backslash from each item in the list but i couldn't make this happened.

code :

```
import os
import shutil

sorc = r'D:\Try\Sorc'
dest = r'D:\Try\Dest'

#variables for sorc
folder_in_sorc = []
files_in_sorc = []

#variables for dest
folder_in_dest = []
files_in_dest = []



for root_sorc, dirs_sorc, files_sorc in os.walk(sorc):
    for folder in dirs_sorc:
        folder_in_sorc.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(root_sorc), folder))

for root_dest, dirs_dest, files_dest in os.walk(dest):
    for folder in dirs_dest:
        files_in_dest.append(os.path.join(root_dest, folder))
print(folder_in_sorc)
```

Comment: It just appears as a double-backslash because that's what `repr` does. It makes a copy-pastable string that you can put back into your python program. It's still a single-backslash in reality.

Comment: Whats the problem with double-backslashs ?

Comment: trying to use it for copy and paste path in windows and the python interpreter doesn't get the double backslash

Comment: Try doing `print('\n'.join(folder_in_sorc))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using forward slashes (I know you are using windows) , they work for me so try it once i guess. Good Luck :)

```py
import os
import shutil

sorc = 'D:/Try/Sorc'
dest = 'D:/Try/Dest'

#variables for sorc
folder_in_sorc = []
files_in_sorc = []

#variables for dest
folder_in_dest = []
files_in_dest = []



for root_sorc, dirs_sorc, files_sorc in os.walk(sorc):
    for folder in dirs_sorc:
        folder_in_sorc.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(root_sorc), folder))

for root_dest, dirs_dest, files_dest in os.walk(dest):
    for folder in dirs_dest:
        files_in_dest.append(os.path.join(root_dest, folder))
print(folder_in_sorc)
```

Comment: sorry it remains the same, i try to get only the path without the double backslash

Comment: wait so you are getting the path in double backslash but you want in single backslash?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing a `list`, so Python prints out the internal representation of the list because it is not 1:1 convertible to a string.
Since backslashes are escape character in Python, they need to be escaped itself.
To solve your issue, print each element in your list to get the real string:

```
import os
import shutil

sorc = r'C:\temp'
dest = r'C:\temp2'
...
for folder in folder_in_sorc:
    print(folder)
```

Out:

```
C:\temp\In
C:\temp\libui
C:\temp\pugi
C:\temp\py2exe-0.6.9
C:\temp\pylibui
C:\temp\pyNuklear
C:\temp\python-exe-unpacker
C:\temp\python-qt5
C:\temp\libui\.git
```